# Por que o "is" não funciona quando comparando o replace de uma string?

Tags: python, string, comparação

Tentei fazer no CLI Python 2.7.6 o seguinte comando:

```
'foo bar'.replace(" ", "") is 'foobar'
```

Mas retornou `False`

Apesar de `'foo bar'.replace(" ", "")` retornar `'foobar'`

Alguém tem alguma explicação lógica para isto?

Answer (score 2):

O comando `is` compara as referências de instâncias de objetos. Se os dois termos de comparação forem referências da mesma instância de objeto então o `is` retornará true. Sua comparação retornará verdadeira se você usar o comando `==`, este compara os valores.

Resumindo:

- == é usado para comparar valores.
- `is` é para comparar referências.

Aí você me contrapõe: ah, mas `'foobar' is 'foobar'` retorna `true`.

É verdade, mas isso acontece porque o Python guarda em cache valores pequenos, por isso que essa comparação `is` podem gerar confusão, acompanhe:

```
>>> s1 = 'foo'
>>> s2 = 'foo'
>>> s1 is s2
True

>>> s1 = 'foo!'
>>> s2 = 'foo!'
>>> s1 is s2
False

>>> 'a' * 20 is 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
True

>>> 'a' * 21 is 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
False
```

Até onde o Python guarda em cache um valor? O que é um valor grande? Um valor pequeno?

Para se aprofundar no assunto eu recomendo a leitura deste artigo:
[Internals in Python](http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/)

Comment: É um detalhe, mas mão é o Python que guarda em cache os valores pequenos, mas o CPython-- a implementação mais usada e oficial de Python. Outras implementações podem fazer diferente.

Comment: Opa, Pablo Almeida, concordo com o que disse. Esses comandos foram feitos em minha máquina rodando CPython. Obrigado pela complementação